# Search and replace in SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, replace, simplexml, str-replace

I loop through an XML file. Once I find a certain node I take it's value and change all it's occurrences in the whole document.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog catalog-id="my_catalog">
<product product-id="11111111">
    ......
    <new-id>aaaaaaa</new-id>
</product>
<product product-id="2222222">
    ......
    <new-id>bbbbbbb</new-id>
</product>
</catalog>
```

For each `<product>` when I find `<new-id>` I need to replace `<product product-id="">` with it which is fine, but also I need to replace all occurrences of `11111111` with `aaaaaaa` in the whole XML document.

**PHP**

```
$cotalog = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
header('Content-Type: text/xml'); 
foreach ($cotalog as $product) {
    if ($product->getName() == 'product') {
        $product['product-id'] = $product->{'new-id'};
        // code here to replace all occurrences of $product['product-id'] with $product->{'new-id'}
        ...
    }
}
echo $cotalog->asXML();
```

Is there a `str_replace` type of way to replace all occurrences of a string value with a different string?

Comment: Look into XSLT, it's for exactly this.

Comment: `all occurrences of 11111111 with aaaaaaa in the whole XML document` - really everywhere? Like a plain full-text search&replace? Or can/must you limit it to certains element values or attributes?

Comment: @VolkerK yes everywhere. In that XML I also have a `product description` node which contains links to products with old ID and I need to update those as well. So plain old full-text search and replace on all nodes :/

Comment: Sorry for nagging but... "links" that sounds like a structure/element to me as in `<node>lalala<a href="someuri/11111">...</a></node>` vs `<node>some plain text without further structure and somewhere 11111 is hidden without any markings</nody>`?

Comment: @VolkerK both cases. Thats why I need the full-text like search and replace.